# name of rule learner algorithm which only compares features with features

Tags: machine-learning

I stumbled upon a classification rule learner which accepts numerical (interval or ratio) features and produces a rule set like

```
    {
      if (feature[1]<feature[2] && feature[2]>feature[4]) return 1;
      if (feature[1]>feature[2] && feature[3]>feature[2]) return 1;
      return 0;
    }
```

This looks like cutting the feature space by diagonal hyperplanes, as opposed to RIPPER and many others, which make their cuts orthogonal to axis (`feature[1]>0.12345`).

I wonder if the above mentioned rule learner has a common name?

I digged so far through Lantz (ISBN 978-1-78216-214-8), Kuhn (ISBN 978-1-4614-6848-6), James (ISBN 978-1-4614-7137-0), but found only algorithms comparing features with (carefully chosen) constant thresholds, never with other features.

For completeness I probably should mention that the rule learner I stumbled upon is built into [Zorro](http://www.zorro-trader.com/manual/en/advisor.htm) as "Pattern Analyzer" and [PriceActionLab](http://www.priceactionlab.com/Literature/pal71manual/pal71manual.html#process4).

Answer (score 0):

Rule output where features are compared with features could be probably achived by first introducing surrogate boolean features like `feature1.less.feature2`, then running a learner on this modified data set and afterwards rendering its output back to tidy `feature[1]<feature[2]`